# How to configure Asp.Net Web Application with IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I am using Asp.Net Standard version 4.7 with MVC and attempting to deploy to IIS Express. I am facing several issues in the configuration and cant seem to find straight forward documentation for asp.Net standard. I added a website named localHost aside from Default Website in IIS. I am facing 2 issues.
 When I click browse from IIS,  it navigates http://localhost/Views/Home/Index.cshtml  I get a 404 error.

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found

When Debugging From Visual studio 2019 I get

> Process with Id of xxxx cant be found
>   .
>   Description: HTTP 404.

I am thinking there some port configuration issue but I am unclear on how to configure.

I attached screenshots of my configuration settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to run it on IIS or IIS Express? They're different applications

Comment: Right now I am trying with IIS Express though I wouldn't mind a pointer or documentation referral  for IIS

Comment: Looks like this was the problem. I changed my debugger to Local IIS and its working

Comment: Second question.  When you set up your site on IIS manager alongside the default site did you add "localhost" as the host name in the site binding - see image 6 in Jalpa Panchal's answer below.  If you didn't then http://localhost will still point to the default website, and you'll find the "Welcome to IIS" landing page at root level rather than your application's home page.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow [Microsoft guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis).

You are trying to access wrong Url. Try below url to access:

```
http://localhost:8080/Home/Index
```

Comment: That guideline is for a sql server database, and  http://localhost:8080/Home/Index doesnt work (site cant be reached), it is also not the address navigated to when I click browse.

Answer (score 1):

To host the site .net application you need to publish it and use that publish folder as site folder path in iis.

1)open visual studio, select your project.

2)right-click on your project and choose publish:

[image]

3)in publish target select folder and create a new folder in c or another drive where can you access the folder.

[image]

4)click on the publish

[image]

5)open iis and create a new site

[image]

6)choose the folder path and site binding

[image]

7)browser your site.

Note:

Assign iis_iusrs and iusr full permission to the site folder. you need to set the physical path credential with your Gmail account.

[image]

Comment: Thats exactly what I did and I get an error, resource can't be found.

Comment: @Curious-programmer from your screenshot it look like that you configured visual studio project path with iis site. but as a correct way you need to configure the publish folder path in iis site.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are misunderstand MVC, you should visit a restful path in mvc instead of cshtml, just like this: **http://localhost:8080/Home/Index** -> to find /Views/Home/Index.cshtml in you solution.